# @EJB in Servlet returns NullPointerException (Intellij, Tomcat)

Tags: jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea, servlets, ejb

I am working on Java Web Application with **JSP, Servlet, EJB, JDBC, Tomcat, and PostgreSQL**, by using **Intellij**.

I am trying to inject my CustomerDAO.java into SignUp.java (Servlet), but it always returns NullPointerException, which is shown below. I hope someone can tell me what I have did wrong. Thank you in advance!

**Message:**

```
Cannot invoke "dao.CustomerDAO.createCustomer(model.Customer)" because "this.customerDAO" is null
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "dao.CustomerDAO.createCustomer(model.Customer)" because "this.customerDAO" is null
    controller.SignUp.doPost(SignUp.java:24)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:563)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:631)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Below are my files to work around.

**JpaEntityManagerFactory.java**

```
package util;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;

public class JpaEntityManagerFactory {

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "postgres";
    private static EntityManagerFactory emFactory;

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if (emFactory == null || !emFactory.isOpen()) {
            emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        }
        return emFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        if (emFactory != null && emFactory.isOpen()) {
            emFactory.close();
        }
    }

}
```

**AbstractFacade.java**

```
package dao;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Root;
import util.JpaEntityManagerFactory;

import java.util.List;

public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private EntityManager em = JpaEntityManagerFactory.getEntityManager();
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public void create(T entity) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(entity);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

**CustomerDAO.java**

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerDAO extends AbstractFacade<Customer> implements CustomerDAOI {

    public CustomerDAO() {
        super(Customer.class);
    }

    public boolean createCustomer(Customer customer){
        try{
            this.create(customer);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**SignUp.java**

```
package controller;

import jakarta.ejb.EJB;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import dao.CustomerDAO;
import model.Customer;

import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "SignUp", value = "/SignUp")
public class SignUp extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Customer customer = new Customer("John");
        customerDAO.createCustomer(customer);   //returns NullPointerException

    }
}
```

Everything only works if I changed this

```
@EJB
private CustomerDAO customerDAO;
```

to

```
@EJB
private CustomerDAO customerDAO = new CustomerDAO();
```

but this is not I want, as I have to apply EJB in my application.

#### Below are steps that I have tried.

1. Installed Jakarta EE EJB Plugin in Intellij.
   customerDAO in `private CustomerDAO customerDAO` once to be greyed out and appear `Private field 'customerDAO' is never assigned`, and this step recovers it.
2. Used **@ManagedBean** and **mappedName** in SignUp.java

```
@WebServlet(name = "SignUp", value = "/SignUp")
@ManagedBean
public class SignUp extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB(mappedName = "CustomerDAO")
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;
```

3. Used **@Local** for CustomerDAOI.java.
4. Added this into src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<ejb-local-ref>
        <ejb-ref-name>CustomerDAO</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <local>dao.CustomerDAO</local>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

Comment: Tomcat doesnt support EJB, it is just a web container. Use compliant Jakarta EE server like [OpenLiberty](https://openliberty.io)

Comment: Hi @Gas , thanks for your input, you're right, can you post it as answer so I can mark it as a correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat doesnt support EJB, it is just a web container. Use compliant Jakarta EE server like [OpenLiberty](https://openliberty.io/)